# Problemas con eclipse : Project has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, eclipse

Estoy intentando compilar un programa en eclipse, y veo que todo lo que escribo me lo pone como error, y cuando ejecuto, me aparece el siguiente mensaje por consola:

> Error: Se ha producido un error de enlace al cargar la clase principal
> Curso_Udemy_106h.Tarea2_DetalleLibro
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> Curso_Udemy_106h/Tarea2_DetalleLibro has been compiled by a more
> recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), this
> version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to
> 61.0

El tema es que todo iba bien hasta que tuve que cambiar de ordenador, y ahora, no me funciona. Este programa lo hice con el otro pc.

¿Alguien sabría decirme que está pasando y como lo soluciono?
¡Gracias!!

Comment: Hola Jesus, si la solución de @Jorgesys no te llega a funcionar, puedes crear un nuevo proyecto con el mismo nombre, luego le agregas los **.java** que tienes y listo.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu mensaje de error:

> "Tarea2_DetalleLibro  has been compiled by a more recent version of
> the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), this version of the Java
> Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0"

Se deduce que el problema se debe a que **tu proyecto fue compilado con la versión 63 de Java que sería java 19, y como minimo deberías usar la versión 61 que es java 17.** Por cierto, no se que realice tu proyecto pero me parece que tal vez estas usando una versión muy alta de java que probablemente sea innecesario.

**La solución es instalar Java 19 o como minimo Java 17, después de instalar, cambia el "Compliance Level" de tu proyecto**.

<kbd>Project menu</kbd> > <kbd>Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Java Compiler</kbd> > <kbd>Compiler compliance level</kbd>

[image: Eclipse Oxigen Jorgesys]